# ITextSharp - VB.NET - PdfTextExtractor - PDF to TXT - missing part of the page text

Tags: pdf, itext

i'm having an issue with PdfTextExtractor GetTextFromPage method where part of the text is missing, no matter if i run all pages .. i still can't find part of the text. i use the same code snipper for all pdf extracting, never had a problem before.. maybe the pdf file is messed up?

i have tried with no strategy, with LocationTextExtractionStrategy and SimpleTextExtractionStrategy ... the result changes a bit, but still cant get all text.

i'm testing against this public document which i need to read some data from and the code snippet to download and get all text is very simple :

```
webc.DownloadFile("http://www.inmetro.gov.br/legislacao/pam/pdf/PAM007426.pdf", "C:\test\PORTARIA.pdf")
pdf = New PdfReader("C:\test\PORTARIA.PDF")

Dim strategy As ITextExtractionStrategy = New LocationTextExtractionStrategy

For i = 1 To pdf.NumberOfPages
   TextBox3.AppendText(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdf, i, strategy)))) + vbNewLine + vbNewLine)
Next
```

i'm interested only at the first page, i need to extract some data .. and can't find words like "fabricante", "marca", "PESO EXATO BALANÇAS" etc

does anyone knows why it is happening ??? And i would love to see other options to achieve this. not paying for tools

Comment: What do you do that `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(...)))` for?

Comment: Please attach sample PDF to reproduce the problem

Comment: @KJ putting i=0 to pdf.numberpages i get an nullpointerexception. i always used 1 .. i cant get this same text you get. how is that possible lol...

Comment: @AlexeySubach you got the link inside the code snippet.

Comment: @mkl i got this line from an example i tried long time ago. i'm creating just a test function right now for a future project. i put the plain-text generated to a textbox/string so i can find patterns to use to read data..

Comment: @KJ i cant do that for thousands of documents. thats why i'm extracting text... ¬¬_

Comment: @fferrandini Did my answer give a starting point from which you could investigate further?

Answer (score 1):

> i'm interested only at the first page, i need to extract some data .. and can't find words like "fabricante", "marca", "PESO EXATO BALANÇAS" etc

I tested as follows:

```vb
Dim pdfReader As New PdfReader("PAM007426.pdf")
Dim strategy As ITextExtractionStrategy = New LocationTextExtractionStrategy

Dim text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, 1, strategy)

Console.WriteLine("Position of 'fabricante': {0}", text.IndexOf("fabricante"))
Console.WriteLine("Position of 'marca': {0}", text.IndexOf("marca"))
Console.WriteLine("Position of 'PESO EXATO BALANÇAS': {0}", text.IndexOf("PESO EXATO BALANÇAS"))
```

The output:

```
Position of 'fabricante': -1
Position of 'marca': 1061
Position of 'PESO EXATO BALANÇAS': 1067
```

As you see, both `"marca"` and `"PESO EXATO BALANÇAS"` are found immediately.

Looking at the PDF it becomes clear why `"fabricante"` cannot be found: That word is not on the page written like that, there merely is `"FABRICANTE"`. Testing

```vb
Console.WriteLine("Position of 'FABRICANTE': {0}", text.IndexOf("FABRICANTE"))
```

returns

```
Position of 'FABRICANTE': 1303
```

Thus, all the words you are missing can be found.

So if you cannot find them in your `TextBox3`, there is some other issue. Maybe its the conversion orgy `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(...)))`, maybe the text box is too full, maybe something else.

Comment: @KJ Right. Here I merely additionally give the test code the OP can start from to identify their issue.

Comment: @fferrandini As an aside, I used the most current iText 5.x version. Maybe some very old version still had some issues mapping to Unicode.